# break from a for loop on the result of an async function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a code where I have to query a firestore collection and get one random document, but if the id of the document is the same as the one I have in my primaryTag, then I need to query the collection again. I am using a small for loop of 5 iterations to test.

```js
let myPrimaryTag = 'abcd1234';
   
 for(let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
 
/* randomTag is an async function which returns a random document from firestore   collection */

     randomTag()
     .then(resultId => {
         
         if(myPrimaryTag == resultId){

            console.log('result is same as primarytag ',result);
            // If resultId is same, need to continue in the loop

         } else {

            console.log('different result encountered ',result);
            // If resultId is not same, then need to break here

          }  
      });
   }
```

I need to know how I can exit from the loop with the result once I get a different resultId? I am new to both firebase and stackoverflow.

Comment: Your loop isn't async, so all the randomTag calls will be made, the loop will end, and then they will begin to resolve. You'll need to `await` the result inside the loop if you want to respond to the result within the iteration.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add code of `randomTag()` function? If you are just trying to fetch random documents where document ID is not equal to `myPrimaryTag` then you might be able to filter that in the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to make a loop that will end only when the correct document is found. It's simple, but it's wrong.

```
const myPrimaryTag = 'abcd1234';

function getNewDocument(primaryTag) {   
  while(true) {
/* randomTag is an async function which returns a random document 
   from firestore   collection */
  randomTag()
    .then(resultId => {
      if(primaryTag !== resultId) {
        return resultId;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(getNewDocument(myPrimaryTag));
```

There are some issues:

- if there's only one document in the database with `primary tag`, then this loop will never end
- we need to use async/await or all the calls into `firebase` will be done at the same time

```
const myPrimaryTag = 'abcd1234';

/* 
   Function will exit if we found the new random document with Id different 
   from the primary tag or if we didn't find such document after 3 attempts
*/
async function getNewDocument(primaryTag) {
  const maxAttempts = 3;
  for(let attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++) {
/* randomTag is an async function which returns a random document 
   from firestore collection */
  const resultId = await randomTag();
  if(primaryTag !== resultId) {
    return resultId;
  }
}

const newDocument = await getNewDocument(myPrimaryTag);
console.log(newDocument);
```